# How make a relationship between tables in different servers?

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, doctrine

I have two tables in different servers and I want to make a relationship. But I can not create a foreign key referring to a table in another server.

What way is the best to do it?
I have an application with Symfony so, maybe if I can't make the relationship in SQL level I can do it with ORM level.

Comment: There is no standard SQL way for this, nor are all ORMs the same. If you have a specific database and ORM in mind please tag those.

Comment: My database is Mysql and the ORM is doctrine